# Only display content in one page (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The problem I am encountering is that I have 3 pages, dashboard (`dashi.html`), stats and log. I have a diagram that takes a lot of memory space and reduces the application performance, the diagram is `$("#dash").load("dashi.html");`.

What I am trying to achieve is only display this content from dashi.html when the user is in dashboard page or want to access the dashboard page. It must then be idle in all other pages..

**How can I make `dashi.html` only be viewable in homepage and not other pages, that is to say only run in homepage and become idle when not viewed?**

Below I have written a JQuery code. It works fine, but dashi.html is causing huge problems.. The

```
<script>

$(function() {

    $("#dash").load("dashi.html");

    $('#selectTable').hide();
    $('#database').hide();
    $('#dash').show();

    $('a#dashboard').on('click', function() {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('#selectTable').hide();
        $('#database').hide();
        $('#dash').show();
    });

    $('a#stats').on('click', function() {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('#database').hide();
        $('#dash').hide();
        $('#selectTable').show();
    });
    $('a#log').click(function() {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('#dash').hide();
        $('#selectTable').hide();
        $('#database').show();
    });
    var pres_row = 0;
    $('[data-row]').on('click', function() {
        var row = $(this).attr('data-row');
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('#table' + row).addClass('active');

        if (row !== pres_row) {
            // clear the currently running interval if any
            if ('diagramInterval' + pres_row in window) {
                clearInterval(window['diagramInterval' + pres_row]);
            }
            pres_row = row;
            // load again only if not loaded
            if ('diagram' + pres_row in window) {
                window['diagram' + pres_row]();
            } else {
                $.getScript("SensorTables/diagram" + pres_row + ".js", function() {
                    window['diagram' + pres_row]();
                });
            }

        }
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Load only on demand when user selects the dashboard. When they switch to another view remove the diagram from the DOM.  See [jQuery remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) method. Knowing what kind of diagram is used might be helpful in answering your question.

Comment: @Robert: 
This seems to work good, but still it samples some few data in between. I think this is because of how the code is structured.

Comment: @Robert, if I remove, this means that it will not come back, right? If so, that is not my wish.

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilize window **blur** and **focus** events:

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).on("blur focus", function(e) {
    if ($(this).data("prevEvent") !== e.type) { //fix events double firing issues
      switch (e.type) {
        case "blur":
          $('body').append('<div style="color:gray">window is inactive...</div>');
          break;
        case "focus":
          $('body').append('<div style="color:red">window is active again...</div>');
          break;
      }
    }
    $(this).data("prevEvent", e.type);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can stop showing animations and doing other heavy tasks on window blur and proceed again after focus.